# psql: Init files?

Tags: postgresql, psql

In the psql documentation, I read information about [variables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-psql.html) (section advanced features), e.g. one of these variables is:

```
HISTSIZE
The number of commands to store in the command history. The default value is 500.
```

Is there a file in the home directory or somewhere else where I can configure these variables?

What syntax would I use in that file?

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the [**Files** section](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#AEN88543), you'll see this:

> **Files**
>
> - Unless it is passed an `-X` or `-c` option, psql attempts to read and execute commands from the system-wide `psqlrc` file and the user's `~/.psqlrc` file before starting up. (On Windows, the user's startup file is named `%APPDATA%\postgresql\psqlrc.conf`.) See `PREFIX/share/psqlrc.sample` for information on setting up the system-wide file. It could be used to set up the client or the server to taste (using the `\set` and `SET` commands).
>
>   The location of the user's `~/.psqlrc` file can also be set explicitly via the `PSQLRC` environment setting.

So like most Unix commands, there is an RC ("Run Commands") file that you can use for configuration, the name also matches the Unix conventions of `~/.cmdrc` so you want `~/.psqlrc`.

The format matches the `\set` commands you'd use within `psql` itself:

```
\set HISTSIZE 11
```

for example.