# Batch script does not change console code page from command prompt

Tags: windows, postgresql, batch-file, cmd

When running `psql <database_name>` from the command line I've been getting this warning:

> WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
>            8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
>            page "Notes for Windows users" for details.

[I found a solution for this found from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794035/postgresql-warning-console-code-page-437-differs-from-windows-code-page-125) however it only gets rid of the warning for that session and I'm trying to completely get rid of the warning. It's been mentioned that I could go into `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\scripts\runpsql.bat` and `cmd.exe /c chcp 1252` or `chcp 1252` near the top of the batch file to remove this warning, however that has not been working for me.

When executing the batch file, it does print out a line console code page and the warning doesn't appear. However when I run `psql [database]` from the command prompt, the warning still persists. Does anyone know how to permanently remove the warning?

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6.1 and Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Look here: [psql: Init files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21518898/psql-init-files)

You can locate the file PSQLRC.CONF and add in it a line like, perhaps,
\set ENCODING "whatever encoding you want"

Comment: I haven't been able to find `postgresql\ `   nor   `psqlrc.conf` in my AppData directory

Comment: Try searching from the root. `CD \ & DIR /S /B psqlrc.conf`. If it could be on a different "drive letter," change to that drive and repeat.

Comment: `File not found.` on my C drive. I don't think there in my other drives since I never touch them (Recovery, Tools & MS Word), I don't even know how to access the terminal for them.

Comment: If the file does not exist, it can be created... but a deep look at the docs for psql must be made.